# How to send details to a php page?

Tags: php, html

How do I send information from a HTML page to a php page which then makes a connection to a database?

This is my code so far on my website: http://jsfiddle.net/xiiJaMiiE/wNraL/

```
<h1>
<div id=signin>  
<input type="text" name="textbox1" value="Username" onfocus="if
(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" size="19%" height="50"/></br>
<input type="password" name="password" value="Password" onfocus="if
(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" size="19%" height="50"/>
</div>
</h1>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: exactly what you want => http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/664241-using-html-forms-pass-data-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `h1` element (you don't have a heading so you shouldn't say you do) with a `form` element.

Give it an `action` attribute that specifies the URL of the PHP program you want to submit the data to.

Since you are sending authentication data, add a `method` attribute that to `POST` the data.

```
<form action="signin.php" method="POST">
  <div id=signin>  
    <label>
      Username
      <input type="text" name="username">
    </label>
    <label>
      Password
      <input type="password" name="password">
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

The data will then be available to PHP via `$_POST['field_name_here']`.

Comment: Hello, I'm very new to web design (a noob if you wish), so I'm not sure how to give it and action attribute, how do I do it?

Comment: There's an example in the answer.

Comment: The field name. As specified by name=.

Comment: ohh sorry I'm a noob haha XD

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id=signin>
    <form action="connection.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="username" value="Username" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" size="19%" height="50"/>
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="Password" onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" size="19%" height="50"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

You can access these passed variables in the conneciton.php file with `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the action attribute to a file that will process form data (eg process. php) and pass form data to your database using $_POST('filedName') on submitting the form.

Comment: there's a typo, it should be $_POST['fieldName']